# How to make a screen scrollable in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, scroll, gesture

I'm creating an app with React Native.
Using `scrollView` works normally(it makes the screen scrollable), but it doesn't work with GestureRecognizer from "react-native-swipe-gestures".

Here is my really simple app.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { ScrollView, Text } from "react-native";
import GestureRecognizer from "react-native-swipe-gestures";

const App = () => {
  const onSwipe = (gestureName) => {
    if (gestureName === "SWIPE_RIGHT") {
      console.log("You swiped right and are going to another screen");
    }
    if (gestureName === "SWIPE_LEFT") {
      console.log("You swiped left and are going to another screen");
    }
  };

  return (
    <GestureRecognizer
      onSwipe={onSwipe}
      config={{ velocityThreshold: 0.3, directionalOffsetThreshold: 80 }}
      style={{ flex: 1 }}
    >
      <ScrollView>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 40 }}>
          This is a scrollable content. This is a scrollable content. This is a
          scrollable content. This is a scrollable content. This is a scrollable
          content. This is a scrollable content. This is a scrollable content.
          This is a scrollable content. This is a scrollable content. This is a
          scrollable content. This is a scrollable content. This is a scrollable
          content. This is a scrollable content. This is a scrollable content.
          This is a scrollable content. This is a scrollable content. This is a
          scrollable content. This is a scrollable content. This is a scrollable
          content. This is a scrollable content. This is a scrollable content.
          This is a scrollable content. This is a scrollable content. This is a
          scrollable content. This is a scrollable content. This is a scrollable
          content. This is a scrollable content. This is a scrollable content.
          This is a scrollable content. This is a scrollable content. This is a
          scrollable content. This is a scrollable content. This is a scrollable
          content. This is a scrollable content. This is a scrollable content.
          This is a scrollable content. This is a scrollable content. This is a
          scrollable content. This is a scrollable content. This is a scrollable
          content. This is a scrollable content. This is a scrollable content.
          This is a scrollable content. This is a scrollable content.
        </Text>
      </ScrollView>
    </GestureRecognizer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I did googled quite a lot, but I couldn't find a solution for this.
But since you usually want to use both swipe left/right to go to a different screen and scroll up/down to read the content on a page, implementing it should be easy...

Could you take a look my code and give me some advice on it.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the GestureRecognizer
Just use ScrollView for the perfect result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I need to make the app go forward/back to another screen by swiping left/right…